# How to use same colormap for multiple figures with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, colormap

I use networkx for a social network analysis and its build-in capabilities to draw parts of the network. I draw 8 different networks based on disciplines. For coloring the nodes, I use a matplotlib colormap. This works fine for each plot individually.

However, I want to use the same colors throughout all 8 graphs, i.e. a value of 0.5 should always refer to the same color. At the moment, the actual color depends on the other colors in the subgraph (e.g., if 0.5 if the maximum it will result in a different color as if 0.5 would be the smallest number).

The `node_color` variable is calculated on the fly, i.e. it contains different values for all 8 subgraphs.

```py
import networkx as nx

for discipline in disciplines:

    #this is the networkx graph
    K = nx.karate_club_graph() #just for illustration

    #in my code, it returns different graphs for each discipline, see below
    #K = filter_graph_by_discipline(discipline)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    pos = nx.spring_layout(K, seed=1)

    #this returns a list of numercial values 
    node_color = [nx.betweenness_centrality(K)[v] for v in K]

    nx.draw_networkx(K, pos, node_color=node_color, cmap=plt.cm.tab10)
```

How to use the same color for the same `betweenness_centrality` value throughout all graphs?

Comment: Obviously you will need to determine the *global* minimum and maximum value *before* plotting anything. Then you can use it inside the loop (probably through a `norm` argument).

Comment: After determining the min and max like @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said.  You can use `vmin`and `vmax`.  According to [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#draw-networkx) they are used to define `Minimum and maximum for node colormap scaling`

Comment: Uff, that was easy... thanks a lot! It works now!